# Java Telegrambots отправка сообщений

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Хочу настроить отправку сообщений пользователям, рассылку типо.

```
 import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
 import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
 import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
 import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;


 public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
private String chat_id;
private String nameUser = "";
Login login = new Login();

  public void sendMsg(SendMessage message, String text, String chat){
      
      chat = "77777";
      text = "test";
      
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();            
        sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);                           
        sendMessage.setChatId(chat);     
      //sendMessage.setReplyToMessageId(message.getMessageId());    
        sendMessage.setText(text);                                 
        try {
           execute(new SendMessage(chat, text));
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 

public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    update.getUpdateId();
    
    
    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage().setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId());
    
    if(update.getMessage().getText().equals("Привет")) {
        sendMessage.setText("hello World.");
        try {
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
     
    
    chat_id = String.valueOf(update.getMessage().getChatId());
    nameUser = update.getMessage().getFrom().getUserName();
    String text = update.getMessage().getText();
    try {
        sendMessage.setText(getMsg(text));
        execute(sendMessage);
        System.out.println(update.getMessage().getFrom().getUserName() + ": " + update.getMessage().getText());
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public String getMsg(String msg) {
/*  if(msg.contains("/remove")){
        msg.replace("/remove", "");
        login.remove(msg);
        
    } */
if(msg.contains("/add")) {
    login.add(nameUser,  chat_id);

}



return "OK";

}

public String getBotUsername() {
    return "";
    
}
public String getBotToken() {
    return "";
    
}
 }
```

и класс для отправки в БД

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Login {

private Connection con;
private Statement st;
private ResultSet rs;

public Login() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:", "", "");
    st = con.createStatement();
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " +e);
    }
}
public String add(String name, String chat_id) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO id(name, chat_id) VALUES(?,?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString( 1, name);
        st.setString( 2, chat_id);
        st.executeUpdate ();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error " +e);
        return "Ne ydaloc dobavit";
        
    }
return "Yspeshno";
}
public void change(String newName, String id_chat) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement( "UPDATE id SET name = ? WHERE chat_id = ?");
        st.setString( 1, newName);;
        st.setString(2, id_chat);
        st.executeUpdate();
        
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        
    }
}

/* public ArrayList getChatID() {
    ArrayList<String> list = null;
try {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    String query = "select * FROM id";
    st = con.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = st.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        list.add(rs.getString( "chat_id"));
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return list;

    }



*/
}
```

Планирую, чтоб при запуске, сразу шла рассылка сообщений всем, кто записался в базу. пока вставил для тест чат ид сразу, но при запуске не идет отправка сообщения. консоль тоже ничего не говорит, ошибок связанных с этим - нет. подскажите, что не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько мне известно бот не может отсылать сообщения пользователям, если они ни разу с ним не общались. Если подставляемое `id` принадлежит пользователю, который не активировал вашего ботаы не сможете ему ничего послать. Первым должен прислать сообщение пользователь, а оттуда уже вы сможете достать `chat_id` по которому можно уже слать сообщение пользователю в ответ, пока у него активен бот.

Comment: человек мне пишет, я записываю его chat_id в базу, а оттуда уже буду делать рассылку раз в сутки, или как там нужно будет. но чат ид есть

Comment: Если, есть возможность, то я бы хотел взглянуть в целом на код программы. Так как в методе ошибок  я не вижу. Может есть ссылка на репозиторий?

Comment: Обновил сообщение, добавил код обоих классов. Мне кажется все же в методе где-то я не так делаю, ведь sendmessage умеет посылать сообщения, зная чат ид, а я его уже записал...

Comment: Если вы ожидаете вызова sendMsg(SendMessage message, String text, String chat), то этого не произойдет, так как метод просто нигде не вызывается, а просто объявлен. LongPollingBot сам с определенной периодичностью опрашивает сервера телеграмм на предмет обновлений, поэтому метод onUpdateReceived(Update update) является точкой входа для активации действий бота. Если же вы вызываете метод sendMsg извне, то лучше предоставьте весь необходимый для понимания программы код.

Comment: Да, действительно протупил, забыл вызвать) прошу прощения. уже разобрался